# Commits history appears in one day only

Tags: git, github

I have a local repository which I had to amend the last 57 commits in order to change the author (fix my email address). I did it this way:

```
// mark commits as 'edit'
git commit --amend --author="My Name <current@email.com>"
git rebase --continue
```

Then I forced a push to its Github repository. When visiting Commits Tab, all the amended commits appear under a single day (the day I pushed):

```
Commits on Mar 28, 2019
fix endianess when reading chunk id
xxxxxx committed on 26 Jan
```

the rest of them, which weren't amended, appears on their own and correct day:

```
Commits on Apr 23, 2018
ignore packet mocks
xxxxxx committed on 23 Apr 2018
```

Did I forgot to amend anything else? Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: To fix this situation, I modified the script I found on [Github's help center](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info):

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

And then, as they say, did:

`git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git commits contain (among other information) 2 dates: the author date and the committer date. When you create a commit, both are at the same value. If you amend a commit, the committer date is changed. Github uses the committer date, which is why all the commits you amended are displayed at the date you amended them.