# How to view author-date on GitHub.com

Tags: github

In Git, there are 2 types of dates: `author-date` and `commit-date`.

[`git log` shows the `author date`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) by default. Similarly, GitHub desktop appears to show the `author-date` by default. However, [GitHub.com shows the `commit-date` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418391/640195).

So far, I was unable to find how to view the `author-date` for a commit on the GitHub.com website. Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63870006/640195) described how to view it in the GitHub API, I didn't find anything on how to view it on the website itself.

Is there any way to view the `author-date` either on the general commit log page or at the individual commit level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `author-date` is part of the [patch format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), you can get it from appending `.patch` while viewing a commit on the GitHub website:

```
https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/commit/<commit-sha>.patch
```

*The `Date` field in the output is what you are searching for:*

```
From dc382172d6824a8f01d36904afefe8d5d3e9c0b7 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: [...] <[...]>
Date: Sun, 12 Mar 2022 11:50:32 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] [...]

---
[...]
```

Comment: There should have been a simpler way, but for now I am afraid that in order to get a better solution we will have to develop a browser extension or bookmarklet